# Oracle SQL query to retrieve data per page with dynamic size?

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets say there is a table with n rows.

I want to set varibles:
 numberOfPages = 10  (page size must be dynamic)
 pageToGet = 2;

Is it possible to retrieve the desired page without specifing page size and number of total rows in table?

Answer (score 2):

Try [`NTILE()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions091.htm):

```
WITH paginated AS (
  SELECT
    columns,
    NTILE(numberOfPages) OVER (ORDER BY what?) AS pageNum
  FROM table
)
SELECT
  columns
FROM paginated
WHERE pageNum = pageToGet
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to apply order? the table is enormous, so i don't want to apply sorting.

Comment: @omrid: Yes, `ORDER BY` clause is mandatory for `NTILE`. In SQL Server I'd have to do something like `... ORDER BY (SELECT 1) ...` to specify an ‘arbitrary’ order in this case, but Oracle might accept just a constant, like `ORDER BY 1.23` or `ORDER BY 'abc'`. I'm not sure, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of articles out there for Oracle pagination queries, but I typically use:

```
select * from (
  select a.*, rownum r
  from (
    select *
    from your_table
    where ...
    order by ...
  ) a
  where rownum <= :upperBound
)
where r >= :lowerBound;
```

Order by is needed, but I usually use indexed columns, and the use of rownum means Oracle can use the stopkey optimization. So, not necessarily going to do full table scan.

So, if you have 100 rows per page, and you want page 3, your lowerBound=301 and upperBound=400.

Using NTILE as AndriyM suggests is a good answer if you absolutely cannot specify a page size, but I believe you'll see definite performance hits on large tables (no stopkey optimization I believe).  Thats primarily why I posted this, so you can compare performance and see if the dynamic page size makes sense for your app.